# How to resume a command pipeline in Ubuntu after accidentally shutting the program down?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line

I am still a beginner in all of this, which is why I'll describe as well as possible. I have been running a pipeline in Ubuntu for more than a day and just accidentally closed the Ubuntu window. The pipeline is part of the Stacks software pipeline for building loci from short-read sequences (genetics, genomics). It consists of different steps, of which some were already executed successfully. As those steps took a very long time to be executed I wondered whether there would be a command for me to let Ubuntu know what it was doing and to resume where it left off? Let me know whether there is any way for me to resume or if I should run it all over again from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

The ability to resume will entirely depend on the application. If you haven't already, I would recommend trying to contact the developers of the software as they will be able to provide you with the best answer.

I believe that this is the developers website for the software you described, you can find some contact information here:
https://catchenlab.life.illinois.edu/stacks/

Their documentation does explicitly mention a "resume" option that **might** be what you're looking for, but running that without input from someone that is familiar with the software could result in dataloss - so I'd recommend waiting for a reply.

> --resume — resume executing the pipeline from a previous run.

Here is the link where that command can be found.

https://catchenlab.life.illinois.edu/stacks/comp/denovo_map.php